# Android FrameLayout and Softkeyboard Issue

Tags: android

I have a FrameLayout with a LinearLayout added to it with a gravity of bottom. As a result the LinearLayout appears at the bottom of the screen, and on top of all other layers. This is my required functionality. However when ever a softkeyboard appears on the screen, it pushes the bottom layout up. As a result that layout hides the fields that i am typing in. What can i do to avoid this ?

Kind Regards,

Answer (score 3):

Add the following attribute to your related activity inside **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```